# How to post JSON data using curl over basic http auth?

Tags: api, rest, curl

I want to post data using curl unix command what I got by googling is doing like below:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST --data '{"description": "This will prbbly be my lst post.", "transaction_id": "2011-05-22T00:46:38", "account": "another-post"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction/
```

But its is returning following response header like below:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Date: Sat, 09 Jun 2012 18:50:37 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

What I am doing wrong

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to write "POST" to make [curl(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) post - it will do that automatically if you give it a `--data` argument.

Instead, it is mistaking "POST" for the URL you want to send to, and failing as you might imagine.  Drop that word and you should be good.